# How to maintain read/unread messages by php

Tags: mysql, message

This question might have been asked many times before this post, but I could not find a suitable answer which perfectly did what I want.

Suppose I have two tables:

```
table-1: table_msg
-------------------------------------------------------
 msg_id |       msg_subject       | create_time
-------------------------------------------------------
    1   | welcome to this site    | 2015-01-01 10:20:30
-------------------------------------------------------
    2   | How to visit this site  | 2015-01-05 10:30:00
--------------------------------------------------------
    3   | Plz pay your member fee | 2015-03-10 09:00:00
--------------------------------------------------------
    4   | Important Notice        | 2015-06-01 12:20:00
--------------------------------------------------------
    5   | Plz change your password| 2015-06-15 13:24:01
--------------------------------------------------------


table-2: table_user
    -------------------------------
     user_id |    last_login
    -------------------------------
        1    | 2015-03-01 07:00:00
    -------------------------------
```

I see solutions almost all the time, that as `user_id-1`'s last login was before `msg_id-3`, so if the `user_id-1` logins on `2015-06-02`, he has 02 new messages `msg_id-3` and `msg_id-4`. Well I can bold the subject of these two messages by css to show it as `UNREAD`. Now suppose after login `user_id-1` opened `msg_id-4` and did not opened `msg_id-3`, so the `msg_id-3` is still `UNREAD`.

Now when the same user again login on `2015-06-20`, then after his last login, `msg_id-5` can be easily identified as `UNREAD` as it was posted after his last login `2015-06-02`, it can be made bold, but what about `msg_id-3` which was posted before his last login but still not opened. It is also `UNREAD` and should be in Bold font.

How can I identify `msg_id-3` as `UNREAD` without a separate table like below:

```
table-3: read_msg
------------------------
 id | user_id | msg_id
------------------------
  1 |    1    |    1
------------------------
  1 |    1    |    2
------------------------
  1 |    1    |    4
------------------------
```

`table-3` is well for a few users, but if users are 5000 in numbers and total messages are 10000 or higher then the table would be a quite large to handle for mysql engine and it will grow geometrically larger even day by day.

Is there any mechanism/technique or algorithm so that together with message that were posted after last login, message which were not opened before last login can also be identified as `UNREAD` without a huge size `read_msg` table?

Comment: 10,000 messages is nothing for MySQL. Millions of rows is trivial with the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

why not just add a column (boolean) with the status (1 = read, 0 = unread) to your table, which upon opening a certain message updates the status to read.

### table-3: read_msg

### id | user_id | msg_id|read

### 1 |    1    |    1|0

### 1 |    1    |    2|1

1 |    1    |    4|0

consider the following scenario:

A user logs in and has 7 unread messages. he chooses to read only 1. If you create a query/algorithm to use his last login time to see unread messages, it will see that he logged in after the messages were posted. but did he read them? no ...

Comment: `read` column can do it (by set it to 1) if there is only one user, but if there are 1000 users or even 2 users, how can you differentiate `1` is for which user, `user_id-1` or `user_id-2` ?

Comment: sorry, thought messages were specific to users, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that, as you've described, you have one table that has the messages. These messages are for everyone. I think that davejal assumes, as I did, that these messages were directed towards each user. In which case, you would have one row in table_msg per message per user. To get the messages for that particular user, the table would have to be:

```
  msg_id |       msg_subject       | create_time        |  read  |user_id|
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1   | welcome to this site    | 2015-01-01 10:20:30|   0    |  1
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     2   | How to visit this site  | 2015-01-05 10:30:00|   0    |  1
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3   | Plz pay your member fee | 2015-03-10 09:00:00|   1    |  1
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     4   | Important Notice        | 2015-06-01 12:20:00|   1    |  1
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     5   | Plz change your password| 2015-06-15 13:24:01|   0    |  1
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then you would simply do:

```
select * from table_msg where user_id = 1 and read = 0;
```

This is the only way I can think of that would avoid having the third table

```
read_msg
```

. The table can get large as some messages will be duplicated, but you can always delete old read messages if you're concerned about that.

Comment: Suppose I have 5000 users, then after giving one post/message, 5000 rows are inserted in the `table_msg`, if average 500 messages were posted each day then about 2500000 rows will be inserted each day. It is normal that every user will not login each day so if average 1000 users will not login for 1 month, can you imagine how many rows there will be in `table_msg` after 1 or 3 months?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but SQL is designed for large data sets. If you index your tables correctly, or simply delete old read messages, this basic selecting simple rows won't be a problem at all. You either have a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship and already know both ways of achieving them.